# 3 short stories—mother and son trapped in cave for years, published in 1980's

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

3 short stories that were published in the 1980's

1. mother and son are trapped in cave for years and mother has a baby by her son
2. a girl becomes a genius then loses her intelligence
3. I can't remember the 3rd story.

A beautician might be involved in the 2nd or 3rd story.

I bought this paperback in late 1980's, then I lost or loaned it, and it was gone from the store when I went back to buy another. It was in an overseas Stars and Stripes store, so I couldn't search elsewhere.

It's been driving me crazy off and on since then!

Comment: [When Darkness Loves Us] by Elizabeth Engstrom has some similarities?

Comment: Just to clarify, it was presumably an anthology which contained more than just these three stories, correct?

Comment: Thank you so much, Ayshe! Wow--you figured out the title and the author - I'm looking forward to rereading it. (I guess I was wrong about 3 stories and the beautician, unless I had a different overseas version.)

Comment: Cool :) I posted it as answer, you can accept it if you're certain that's the book.

Comment: @MaryK: Incidentally, since it seems you're new here, all you need to do to accept the answer is to click on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 5):

[When Darkness Loves Us](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/868727.When_Darkness_Loves_Us) by Elizabeth Engstrom

It consists of two novellas:

**When Darkness Loves Us**

> Sally Ann is a bright and bubbling farm girl, still caught in the
>   thrill of a brand-new husband and a shining future ahead. When a
>   careless exploration leaves her trapped underground, she learns to
>   live again in the absence of everything she once knew. Even driven by
>   love and light, Sally Ann finds the deepest darkness within herself in
>   When Darkness Loves Us.

**Beauty Is**

> Old Martha Mannes has been a part of Morgan, Illinois since her birth.
>   The whole town knows her as the dim-witted woman who was born without
>   a nose, but Martha's mind wasn't always a blank slate. Unlocking the
>   monster buried deep in her memories may bring back the sparkling child
>   she once was...or it may send those around her crashing down into the
>   nightmares of a little girl gone wrong.